# Finding a conditional min date on tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a database with lots of records that have a date

I want to show the minimum date where there is no different booking type after that date

With these fields

```
Date, Booking type, Id

ID   |   Date   |   Booking type

123     01/04         A

123     01/05         B

123     01/06         A

123     01/07         A
```

So I would only want to show record on date 01/06 for ID 123 booking type 'A' as there has not been a different booking type after that

At the moment I can only get date 01/04 for booking type A id 123

Comment: You will need to use LOD and count

Answer (score 0):

First you calculate how many distinct Booking Type there is for each ID and Date

```
{FIXED [ID], [Date]: COUNTD([Booking Type])}
```

Once done, you can do a filter where `SUM(....) > 1`